# Metal draw one object with texture one object without texture

Tags: metal

I want to render 2 different objects with Metal...one is with texture, the other one is without texture. I have 2 different shaders, 2 different vertex descriptors, is that means i should use 2 different render pipeline? .. There is only one object drawing (the model with out texture)on the screen correct, the other one is wrong, I don't know where I went wrong.... Here is the code:

```
     override func buildPipeline() {
        //Model
        let library = device!.newDefaultLibrary()!
        let pipelineDescriptor = MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor()

        buildPipelinForSky(pipelineDescriptor, library: library)
        buildPipelineForModel(pipelineDescriptor, library: library)

        do {
            pipelineSky = try device!.newRenderPipelineStateWithDescriptor(pipelineDescriptor)
        } catch {
            print("error with device.newRenderPipelineStateWithDescriptor")
        }



        let depthStencilDescriptor = MTLDepthStencilDescriptor()
        depthStencilDescriptor.depthCompareFunction = .Less
        depthStencilDescriptor.depthWriteEnabled = true
        depthStencilState = device!.newDepthStencilStateWithDescriptor(depthStencilDescriptor)
        commandQueue = device!.newCommandQueue()

        }

    func buildPipelineForModel(pipeLineDesc:MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor, library: MTLLibrary) -> MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor {

        let vertexFunctionModel = library.newFunctionWithName("vertex_ply")
        let fragmentFunctionModel = library.newFunctionWithName("fragment_ply")

        let vertexDescriptorModel = MTLVertexDescriptor()
        vertexDescriptorModel.attributes[0].offset = 0
        vertexDescriptorModel.attributes[0].format = .Float4
        vertexDescriptorModel.attributes[0].bufferIndex = 0
        vertexDescriptorModel.layouts[0].stepFunction = .PerVertex
        vertexDescriptorModel.layouts[0].stride = sizeof(Float) * 4

        pipeLineDesc.vertexFunction = vertexFunctionModel
        pipeLineDesc.vertexDescriptor = vertexDescriptorModel
        pipeLineDesc.fragmentFunction = fragmentFunctionModel
        pipeLineDesc.colorAttachments[0].pixelFormat = .BGRA8Unorm

        return pipeLineDesc
    }


    func buildPipelinForSky(pipeLineDesc:MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor, library: MTLLibrary ) -> MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor{
        let vertexFunctionSky = library.newFunctionWithName("vertex_sky")
        let fragmentFunctionSky = library.newFunctionWithName("fragment_sky")

        let vertexDescriptorSky = MTLVertexDescriptor()
        vertexDescriptorSky.attributes[0].offset = 0
        vertexDescriptorSky.attributes[0].format = .Float4
        vertexDescriptorSky.attributes[0].bufferIndex = 0
        vertexDescriptorSky.attributes[1].offset = sizeof(Float32) * 4
        vertexDescriptorSky.attributes[1].format = .Float4
        vertexDescriptorSky.attributes[1].bufferIndex = 0
        vertexDescriptorSky.attributes[2].offset = sizeof(Float32) * 8
        vertexDescriptorSky.attributes[2].format = .Float2
        vertexDescriptorSky.attributes[2].bufferIndex = 0
        vertexDescriptorSky.layouts[0].stepFunction = .PerVertex
        vertexDescriptorSky.layouts[0].stride = sizeof(Vertex)

        pipeLineDesc.vertexFunction = vertexFunctionSky
        pipeLineDesc.vertexDescriptor = vertexDescriptorSky
        pipeLineDesc.fragmentFunction = fragmentFunctionSky
        pipeLineDesc.depthAttachmentPixelFormat = .Depth32Float

        let samplerDescriptorSky = MTLSamplerDescriptor()
        samplerDescriptorSky.minFilter = .Nearest
        samplerDescriptorSky.magFilter = .Linear
        samplerStateSky = device!.newSamplerStateWithDescriptor(samplerDescriptorSky)

        return pipeLineDesc

    }

    override func buildResources() {
//        (vertexBuffer, indexBuffer) = SphereGenerator.sphereWithRadius(1, stacks: 30, slices: 30, device: device!)
        //Model
        (vertexBufferModel,normalBufferModel,colorBufferModel) = PointCloud.model(device!)
        uniformBufferModel = device!.newBufferWithLength(sizeof(M4f) * 2, options: .OptionCPUCacheModeDefault)
        //Sky
        vertexBufferSky = SkySphere.sphere(device!)
        uniformBufferSky = device!.newBufferWithLength(sizeof(M4f) * 2, options: .OptionCPUCacheModeDefault)
        diffuseTextureSky = self.textureForImage(UIImage(named: "bluemarble")!, device: device!)


    }

    override func resize() {
        //Model
        super.resize()
        //Sky
        let layerSizeSky = metalLayer.drawableSize
        let depthTextureDescriptorSky = MTLTextureDescriptor.texture2DDescriptorWithPixelFormat(.Depth32Float,
                                                                                                width: Int(layerSizeSky.width),
                                                                                                height: Int(layerSizeSky.height),
                                                                                                mipmapped: false)
        depthTextureSky = device!.newTextureWithDescriptor(depthTextureDescriptorSky)
    }

    override func draw() {
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(inflightSemaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)

        //Sky
        if let drawable = metalLayer.nextDrawable()
        {
            var modelMatrixTransSky = M4f()
            var modelMatrixRotSky = M4f()
            var modelMatrixScaleSky = M4f()

            modelMatrixTransSky = translate(0, y: 0, z: 0)
            modelMatrixRotSky = rotate(90, r: V3f(1,0,0)) * modelMatrixRotSky
            modelMatrixScaleSky = scaling(10, y: 10, z: 10)

            let modelMatrixSky = modelMatrixTransSky * modelMatrixRotSky * modelMatrixScaleSky
            var viewMatrixSky = M4f()
            viewMatrixSky = myCamera.setLookAt(viewMatrixSky)

            let modelViewMatrixSky = viewMatrixSky * modelMatrixSky

            let aspect = Float32(metalLayer.drawableSize.width) / Float32(metalLayer.drawableSize.height)
            let kFOVY:Float = 85.0
            let projectionMatrix = perspective_fov(kFOVY, aspect: aspect, near: 0.1, far: 180.0)

            let matricesSky = [projectionMatrix, modelViewMatrixSky]
            memcpy(uniformBufferSky.contents(), matricesSky, Int(sizeof(M4f) * 2))

            let commandBufferSky = commandQueue.commandBuffer()
            commandBufferSky.addCompletedHandler{ [weak self] commandBufferSky in
                if let strongSelf = self {
                    dispatch_semaphore_signal(strongSelf.inflightSemaphore)
                }
                return
            }

            //Model
            var modelMatrixTransModel = M4f()
            var modelMatrixRotModel = M4f()
            var modelMatrixScaleModel = M4f()

            modelMatrixTransModel = translate(0, y: 0, z: 0)
            modelMatrixRotModel = rotate(0, r: V3f(1,0,0))
            modelMatrixScaleModel = scaling(10, y: 10, z: 10)

            let modelMatrixModel = modelMatrixTransModel * modelMatrixRotModel * modelMatrixScaleModel
            var viewMatrixModel = M4f()
            viewMatrixModel = myCamera.setLookAt(viewMatrixModel)

            let modelViewMatrixModel = viewMatrixModel * modelMatrixModel

            let matricesModel = [projectionMatrix, modelViewMatrixModel]
            memcpy(uniformBufferModel.contents(), matricesModel, Int(sizeof(M4f) * 2))


            //Sky
            let passDescriptor = MTLRenderPassDescriptor()
            passDescrForSky(passDescriptor, drawable: drawable)
            passDescrForModel(passDescriptor, drawable: drawable)

            //Sky
            let commandEncoderSky = commandBufferSky.renderCommandEncoderWithDescriptor(passDescriptor)

            commandEncoderSky.setRenderPipelineState(pipelineSky)
            commandEncoderSky.setDepthStencilState(depthStencilState)
            commandEncoderSky.setFrontFacingWinding(.CounterClockwise)
            commandEncoderSky.setCullMode(.Back)
            pointCloudDraw(commandEncoderSky)
            skyDraw(commandEncoderSky)
            commandEncoderSky.endEncoding()
            commandBufferSky.presentDrawable(drawable)

            // bufferIndex matches the current semaphore controled frame index to ensure writing occurs at the correct region in the vertex buffer
            bufferIndex = (bufferIndex + 1) % MaxBuffers
            commandBufferSky.commit()
        }
    }

    func passDescrForModel(passDescriptor: MTLRenderPassDescriptor, drawable: CAMetalDrawable) -> MTLRenderPassDescriptor{
        passDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].texture = drawable.texture
        passDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].clearColor = MTLClearColorMake(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1)
        passDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].loadAction = .Clear
        passDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].storeAction = .Store
        return passDescriptor
    }

    func passDescrForSky(passDescriptor: MTLRenderPassDescriptor, drawable: CAMetalDrawable) -> MTLRenderPassDescriptor{
        passDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].texture = drawable.texture
        passDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].clearColor = MTLClearColorMake(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1)
        passDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].loadAction = .Clear
        passDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].storeAction = .Store

        passDescriptor.depthAttachment.texture = depthTextureSky
        passDescriptor.depthAttachment.clearDepth = 1
        passDescriptor.depthAttachment.loadAction = .Clear
        passDescriptor.depthAttachment.storeAction = .DontCare

        return passDescriptor

    }

    func pointCloudDraw(commandencodeModel: MTLRenderCommandEncoder)  {

        commandencodeModel.setVertexBuffer(vertexBufferModel, offset:0, atIndex:0)
        commandencodeModel.setVertexBuffer(normalBufferModel, offset:0, atIndex:1)
        commandencodeModel.setVertexBuffer(colorBufferModel, offset:0, atIndex:2)
        commandencodeModel.setVertexBuffer(uniformBufferModel, offset:0, atIndex:3)
        commandencodeModel.setFragmentBuffer(uniformBufferModel, offset: 0, atIndex: 0)
        commandencodeModel.drawPrimitives(.Point, vertexStart: 0, vertexCount: vertextCountModel)
    }

    func skyDraw(commandencodeSky: MTLRenderCommandEncoder) {

        commandencodeSky.setVertexBuffer(vertexBufferSky, offset:0, atIndex:0)
        commandencodeSky.setVertexBuffer(uniformBufferSky, offset:0, atIndex:1)
        commandencodeSky.setFragmentTexture(diffuseTextureSky, atIndex: 0)
        commandencodeSky.setFragmentSamplerState(samplerStateSky, atIndex: 0)
        commandencodeSky.drawPrimitives(.Triangle, vertexStart: 0, vertexCount: vertexCountSky)
    }
```

[image]

here is the vertex buffer for the sky:

```
struct Vector4
{
    var x: Float32
    var y: Float32
    var z: Float32
    var w: Float32
}

struct TexCoords
{
    var u: Float32
    var v: Float32
}

struct Vertex
{
    var position: Vector4
    var normal: Vector4
    var texCoords: TexCoords
}

var vertexCountSky: Int = 0

struct SkySphere
{
    static func sphere(device: MTLDevice) -> (MTLBuffer!)
    {

        let ply = plyVntReader.init(objFileName: "test")
        let vertexBuffer = device.newBufferWithBytes(ply!.vertices, length:sizeof(Vertex) * ply!.vertexCount, options:.OptionCPUCacheModeDefault)

        print(ply!.vertices)
        vertexCountSky = ply!.vertexCount
        return (vertexBuffer)

    }
}
```

And here is vertex buffer for the model:

```
var vertextCountModel: Int = 0

struct PointCloud
{
    static func model(device: MTLDevice) -> (MTLBuffer!, MTLBuffer!, MTLBuffer!)
    {

        let ply = plyVncReader.init(objFileName: "controller_ascii")
        vertextCountModel = ply!.vertexCount

        let vertexBuffer = device.newBufferWithBytes(ply!.vertices, length:sizeof(V4f) * ply!.vertexCount, options:.OptionCPUCacheModeDefault)
        let normalBuffer = device.newBufferWithBytes(ply!.normals, length:sizeof(V4f) * ply!.vertexCount, options:.OptionCPUCacheModeDefault)
        let colorBuffer = device.newBufferWithBytes(ply!.colors, length:sizeof(V4f) * ply!.vertexCount, options:.OptionCPUCacheModeDefault)

        print(ply!.colors)
        return (vertexBuffer, normalBuffer, colorBuffer)

    }
}
```

shaders for the sky

```
using namespace metal;

//Sky
struct TexturedInVertex
{
    packed_float4 position [[attribute(0)]];
    packed_float4 normal [[attribute(1)]];
    packed_float2 texCoords [[attribute(2)]];

};

struct TexturedColoredOutVertex
{
    float4 position [[position]];
    float3 normal;
    float2 texCoords;
    float pointsize[[point_size]];

};

struct UniformsSky
{
    float4x4 projectionMatrix;
    float4x4 modelViewMatrix;
};

vertex TexturedColoredOutVertex vertex_sky(device TexturedInVertex *vert [[buffer(0)]],
                                           constant UniformsSky &uniforms [[buffer(1)]],
                                           uint vid [[vertex_id]])
{
    float4x4 MV = uniforms.modelViewMatrix;
    float3x3 normalMatrix(MV[0].xyz, MV[1].xyz, MV[2].xyz);
    float4 modelNormal = vert[vid].normal;

    TexturedColoredOutVertex outVertex;
    outVertex.position = uniforms.projectionMatrix * uniforms.modelViewMatrix * float4(vert[vid].position);
    outVertex.normal = normalMatrix * modelNormal.xyz;
    outVertex.texCoords = vert[vid].texCoords;
    outVertex.pointsize = 10.0;

    return outVertex;
};

fragment half4 fragment_sky(TexturedColoredOutVertex vert [[stage_in]],
                            texture2d<float, access::sample> diffuseTexture [[texture(0)]],
                            sampler samplr [[sampler(0)]])
{
    float4 diffuseColor = diffuseTexture.sample(samplr, vert.texCoords);
    return half4(diffuseColor.r, diffuseColor.g, diffuseColor.b, 1);
};
```

here is shader for the model
//model

```
struct ColoredVertex
{
    float4 position [[position]];
    float4 normal;
    float4 color;
    float pointsize[[point_size]];

};

struct UniformsPoint
{
    float4x4 projectionMatrix;
    float4x4 modelViewMatrix;
};

vertex ColoredVertex vertex_ply(constant float4 *position [[buffer(0)]],
                                constant float4 *normal [[buffer(1)]],
                                constant float4 *color [[buffer(2)]],
                                constant UniformsPoint &uniforms [[buffer(3)]],
                                uint vid [[vertex_id]])
{    
    ColoredVertex vert;
    vert.position = uniforms.projectionMatrix * uniforms.modelViewMatrix * position[vid];
    vert.normal = normal[vid];
    vert.color = color[vid];
    vert.pointsize = 5.0;

    return vert;
}

fragment float4 fragment_ply(ColoredVertex vert [[stage_in]])
{
    return vert.color;
}
```

Comment: How does what you're seeing differ from the expected output?

Comment: As you can see from the pic, the model is good, it is drawing by point without texture,, but the sphere which is the sky,,, this one is wrong,,,it is drawing by triangle and with texture...@warrenm

Comment: It likes like there may not be agreement between the data layout in your vertex buffer and what's expected by your vertex function, possibly due to padding. I'd capture a frame (Xcode: Debug > Capture GPU Frame) and inspect the buffer. Can you share the definition of the vertex structure(s) you're declaring in your Swift code and your shader file?

Comment: vertex buffer and shader are correct, I think, because when I separate those two objects in 2 different projects, the sky and the model are both drawing correct...when i combine those 2 into one project, the error happens...@ warrenm

Comment: Since you have a project that renders the sky correctly, I would think the next step would be capturing a frame and using the buffer viewer to make sure the model data in the buffer is identical between the two projects at runtime.Your struct layouts appear to match, but given the same pipeline, the same shaders, and the same data, you'd expect the same output, so one or more of them must differ.

Comment: Indeed, the shaders and data are different. I want to use different render pipelines but,,,you said there is only one command buffer...So I have no idea about how to mange 2 render pipelines using one commandEncoder...any tips? @warrenm

Comment: Sorry, I just meant to say that if it's working in one project, but not in another, that gives you a good starting point for investigating what's going wrong. As for using two render pipelines in a single command buffer and single encoder, you just set whatever pipeline state you want on the encoder before drawing, and that will be the pipeline that gets used for the draw call.

Comment: When I use 2 pipelines to draw those 2 objects, only one is showing up, the last one overlaps the first one...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37846174/metal-render-with-2-pipelines @warrenm