# Metal GPU buffers not in sync with CPU

Tags: swift, metal

I'm trying to add multiple objects to the scene, starting from Xcode 9's Metal Game App template.

I've modified the default Game template as little as possible, to render multiple objects, based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37424817/518169

My problem is that the second object doesn't appear. Adding print lines show the buffer is updated on the CPU, but using GPU frame capture I can see that on the GPU it's not. What is happening actually is that the second cube's state is used for both draw calls. With `setVertexBytes` this doesn't happen.

Minimal case: Xcode 9 / New Cross-platform Game using Metal, and replaced the drawIndexedPrimitives part to this:

```
// left cube
var modelMatrix = matrix4x4_translation(-3, 0, 0)
var viewMatrix = matrix4x4_translation(0.0, 0.0, -8.0)
uniforms[0].modelViewMatrix = simd_mul(viewMatrix, modelMatrix)
print(uniforms[0])
for submesh in mesh.submeshes {
  renderEncoder.drawIndexedPrimitives(type: submesh.primitiveType, indexCount: submesh.indexCount, indexType: submesh.indexType, indexBuffer: submesh.indexBuffer.buffer, indexBufferOffset: submesh.indexBuffer.offset)
}

// right cube
modelMatrix = matrix4x4_translation(3, 0, 0)
viewMatrix = matrix4x4_translation(0.0, 0.0, -8.0)
uniforms[0].modelViewMatrix = simd_mul(viewMatrix, modelMatrix)
print(uniforms[0])
for submesh in mesh.submeshes {
  renderEncoder.drawIndexedPrimitives(type: submesh.primitiveType, indexCount: submesh.indexCount, indexType: submesh.indexType, indexBuffer: submesh.indexBuffer.buffer, indexBufferOffset: submesh.indexBuffer.offset)
}
```

The skeleton of the full file looks like this (for future reference):

```
let alignedUniformsSize = (MemoryLayout<Uniforms>.size & ~0xFF) + 0x100
let maxBuffersInFlight = 3

class Renderer: NSObject, MTKViewDelegate {
  var dynamicUniformBuffer: MTLBuffer
  let inFlightSemaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: maxBuffersInFlight)
  var uniformBufferOffset = 0
  var uniformBufferIndex = 0
  var uniforms: UnsafeMutablePointer<Uniforms>

  init?(metalKitView: MTKView) {
    let uniformBufferSize = alignedUniformsSize * maxBuffersInFlight
    guard let buffer = self.device.makeBuffer(length: uniformBufferSize, options: [MTLResourceOptions.storageModeShared]) else { return nil }
    dynamicUniformBuffer = buffer
    uniforms = UnsafeMutableRawPointer(dynamicUniformBuffer.contents()).bindMemory(to: Uniforms.self, capacity: 1)
  }

  private func updateDynamicBufferState() {
    uniformBufferIndex = (uniformBufferIndex + 1) % maxBuffersInFlight
    uniformBufferOffset = alignedUniformsSize * uniformBufferIndex
    uniforms = UnsafeMutableRawPointer(dynamicUniformBuffer.contents() + uniformBufferOffset).bindMemory(to: Uniforms.self, capacity: 1)
  }

  func draw(in view: MTKView) {
    _ = inFlightSemaphore.wait(timeout: DispatchTime.distantFuture)
    if let commandBuffer = commandQueue.makeCommandBuffer() {
      let semaphore = inFlightSemaphore
      commandBuffer.addCompletedHandler { (_) -> Swift.Void in semaphore.signal()}

      updateDynamicBufferState()
      updateGameState()

      if let renderPassDescriptor = view.currentRenderPassDescriptor, let renderEncoder = commandBuffer.makeRenderCommandEncoder(descriptor: renderPassDescriptor) {
        renderEncoder.setCullMode(.back)
        renderEncoder.setRenderPipelineState(pipelineState)
        renderEncoder.setVertexBuffer(dynamicUniformBuffer, offset: uniformBufferOffset, index: BufferIndex.uniforms.rawValue)
        renderEncoder.setFragmentBuffer(dynamicUniformBuffer, offset: uniformBufferOffset, index: BufferIndex.uniforms.rawValue)
        for (index, element) in mesh.vertexDescriptor.layouts.enumerated() {
          guard let layout = element as? MDLVertexBufferLayout else {return}
          if layout.stride != 0 {
            let buffer = mesh.vertexBuffers[index]
            renderEncoder.setVertexBuffer(buffer.buffer, offset: buffer.offset, index: index)
          }
        }
        renderEncoder.setFragmentTexture(colorMap, index: TextureIndex.color.rawValue)

        // left cube
        var modelMatrix = matrix4x4_translation(-3, 0, 0)
        var viewMatrix = matrix4x4_translation(0.0, 0.0, -8.0)
        uniforms[0].modelViewMatrix = simd_mul(viewMatrix, modelMatrix)
        print(uniforms[0])
        for submesh in mesh.submeshes {
          renderEncoder.drawIndexedPrimitives(type: submesh.primitiveType, indexCount: submesh.indexCount, indexType: submesh.indexType, indexBuffer: submesh.indexBuffer.buffer, indexBufferOffset: submesh.indexBuffer.offset)
        }

        // right cube
        modelMatrix = matrix4x4_translation(3, 0, 0)
        viewMatrix = matrix4x4_translation(0.0, 0.0, -8.0)
        uniforms[0].modelViewMatrix = simd_mul(viewMatrix, modelMatrix)
        print(uniforms[0])
        for submesh in mesh.submeshes {
          renderEncoder.drawIndexedPrimitives(type: submesh.primitiveType, indexCount: submesh.indexCount, indexType: submesh.indexType, indexBuffer: submesh.indexBuffer.buffer, indexBufferOffset: submesh.indexBuffer.offset)
        }

        renderEncoder.endEncoding()
        if let drawable = view.currentDrawable {
          commandBuffer.present(drawable)
        }
      }
      commandBuffer.commit()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You should use the Capture GPU Frame tool in Xcode to ensure that all of the relevant state is what you think it is, and that all of your expected draw calls are actually being issued. Many things could be going wrong here; for example, it's not obvious from reading this code whether `uniforms` aliases to the dynamic uniform buffer at the correct offset. It looks like you might always be writing the model-view matrix into the same index. Capturing and inspecting the frame should reveal whether that's the case and point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks. I've Captured the GPU frame which told me that the GPU is reflecting the last object's state. The CPU's print line tells me otherwise at the same time. I've updated the question as best as I could.